# Need to optimize MDX Query

Tags: optimization, ssas, mdx

I have built this query through BIDS Query Designer. But I want to optimize this query by removing SELECTS inside outermost FROM Clause and having only cube in from clause and rest filter on where or filter clause:

```
    SELECT { [Measures].[User ID Distinct Count], [Measures].[Post Count], [Measures].[Like Count], [Measures].[Comment Count], [Measures].[Impressions Master Count] } ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY { ([Section Master].[Section Name].[Section Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Post Master].[Post Name].[Post Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Post Master].[SP Insert Date].[SP Insert Date].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
 FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@SectionMasterSectionName) ) ON COLUMNS 
        FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOMEMBER(@FromDimDateDate) : STRTOMEMBER(@ToDimDateDate) ) ON COLUMNS 
        FROM [AnalyticsCube])) 
 CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

I am quite new in MDX and don't know much in regards to MDX query optimization. And Because of that I also don't know that this is the Optimized version of query or there is still scope for optimization in this. My cube structure is shown in Image.

[image]

I have Update my old query by doing some changes in Row and Column Part, but still stuck with From Clause part

```
SELECT { [Measures].[User ID Distinct Count], 
          [Measures].[Post Count], 
          [Measures].[Like Count], 
          [Measures].[Comment Count], 
          [Measures].[Impressions Master Count] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { ([Section Master].[Section Name].CHILDREN) * 
             ([Post Master].[Post Name].CHILDREN, [Post Master].[SP Insert Date].CHILDREN ) } ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@SectionMasterSectionName) ) ON COLUMNS 
       FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOMEMBER(@FromDimDateDate) : STRTOMEMBER(@ToDimDateDate) ) ON COLUMNS 
              FROM [AnalyticsCube]))
```

Comment: Is that MDX query gives you the correct result?

Comment: Yes it giving me result as expected

Comment: Can you please provide the sample query results?

Comment: @PreetishChindarkar I'm still a little unsure what the question is - looking at your second query what do you want to achieve? You want to get rid of the sub-selects ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the initial simplification:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[User ID Distinct Count]
   ,[Measures].[Post Count]
   ,[Measures].[Like Count]
   ,[Measures].[Comment Count]
   ,[Measures].[Impressions Master Count]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Section Master].[Section Name].Children
      * 
        (
          [Post Master].[Post Name].Children
         ,[Post Master].[SP Insert Date].Children
        )
    } ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    StrToSet(@SectionMasterSectionName) ON 0,
    StrToMember(@FromDimDateDate) : StrToMember(@ToDimDateDate) ON 1
  FROM [AnalyticsCube]
);
```

Then it seems odd to me that you don't move `StrToSet(@SectionMasterSectionName)` into the main SELECT clause:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[User ID Distinct Count]
   ,[Measures].[Post Count]
   ,[Measures].[Like Count]
   ,[Measures].[Comment Count]
   ,[Measures].[Impressions Master Count]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        StrToSet(@SectionMasterSectionName)
      * 
        (
          [Post Master].[Post Name].Children
         ,[Post Master].[SP Insert Date].Children
        )
    } ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    StrToMember(@FromDimDateDate) : StrToMember(@ToDimDateDate) ON 0
  FROM [AnalyticsCube]
);
```

Logically it is slightly different but you could then think about using a `WHERE` clause rather than a `SUB-SELECT`:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[User ID Distinct Count]
   ,[Measures].[Post Count]
   ,[Measures].[Like Count]
   ,[Measures].[Comment Count]
   ,[Measures].[Impressions Master Count]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        StrToSet(@SectionMasterSectionName)
      * 
        (
          [Post Master].[Post Name].Children
         ,[Post Master].[SP Insert Date].Children
        )
    } ON ROWS
FROM [AnalyticsCube]
WHERE 
  StrToMember(@FromDimDateDate) : StrToMember(@ToDimDateDate);
```